# Regex search and replace in VI

Tags: regex, vim

I have a document with lots of <swf...>.....</swf> in it. I would like to remove all these. Using vi when i type

```
:%s/\<swf[^\/swf>]+\/swf\>//g
```

I was hoping this would work, but it doesn't match anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can remove all those from the buffer with this command:

```
:%s!<swf.\{-}/swf>!!
```

if you also have tags that might be split on two lines, you can add the `\_` modifier to make `.` match newlines too:

```
:%s!<swf\_.\{-}/swf>!!
```

this assuming you want to remove both the tags and what they contain, if you just want to get rid of the tags and keep the content

```
:%s!</\?swf.\{-}>!!
```

Notes:

- you don't need to escape `<` or `>`
- you can choose whatever pattern delimiter you wish: Vim will use the first character you put after the `s` in the substitute command: this takes away the need to escape forward slashes in your pattern

EDIT: extending my answer after your comment

- this is exactly like /STRING/REPLACE/g I only used a `!` instead of `/` so that I don't have to quote the backslash in the pattern (see my second point above)
- I didn't add the `g` modifier at the end since I have `:set gdefault` in my `.vimrc` since forever (it means that by default Vim will substitute all matches in a line instead of just the first, thus reverting the meaning of `/g`)
- `\{-}` is the "ungreedy" version of the `*` quantifier, i.e. it matches 0 or more of the preceding atom but take **as few as possible** -- this helps you make sure that your search pattern will extend to the first "closing tag" instead of the last.

HTH

Comment: Thank you thank you, that works a treat!!
 
I'm curious though, how does this work without using /STRING/REPLACE/g format? And what does the {-} mean?

Comment: Updated my answer with details about your comment

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the `[]` is a character class, so you are telling it that between the swf opening and closing tags, the letters `s`, `w` and `f` cannot appear anywhere, in any order.

You could try a non-greedy match instead:

```
\<swf.\{-}\/swf\>
```

Note that `.` does not allow newline by default.

I don't use Vim though, so I used this [guide](http://www.softpanorama.org/Editors/Vimorama/vim_regular_expressions.shtml) to discover the syntax. I hope it is correct.